# numeric and float validation not success

Tags: javascript

i have a function to validate (accept only integer and float)

```
function isNumeric(prodFilterValue)
{
    if((parseFloat(prodFilterValue) == parseInt(prodFilterValue)) && !isNaN(prodFilterValue))
    {
        alert('numeric');       
        alert('hahahahhahaha');
        $("#valuetxt1").css('background-color', 'white');           

    }
    else
    {
        alert('HIIIIIIIIIII');
        $("#valuetxt1").css('background-color', 'grey');
    }

    return prodFilterValue;
}
```

the problem now is.. 
when validate 0.1 it will say it is not numeric..
suppose to be it is numeric..
when i put another condition

```
if((parseFloat(prodFilterValue) == parseInt(prodFilterValue)) && !isNaN(prodFilterValue) || (prodFilterValue % 1 !=0))
```

it will validate 1A as numeric

Comment: Try this method used in Backbone http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188998/obj-length-obj-length-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Check it using Number conversion:

```
 !isNaN(Number([value]));
 // e.g.
 isNumber = !isNaN(Number('.3421')); //=> true
 isNumber = !isNaN(Number('nonumber.3421')); //=> false
 isNumber = !isNaN(Number('1500032')); //=> true
 // you can also just use the conversion 
 isNumber = Number('.3421'); //=> 0.3421
 isNumber = Number('nonumer.3421'); //=> NaN
 if (!isNumber) { /*...*/ }
 // a hidden goodie: Number automatically trims the parameter
 isNumber = Number('    .3421 ');   //=> 0.3421
 isNumber = Number('    .3421 \n'); //=> 0.3421
```

Applied to your function:

```
function isNumeric(prodFilterValue,thousandsDelim) {
  prodFilterValue = Number(prodFilterValue);
  return prodFilterValue 
            ? (alert('yeah!'), prodFilterValue) 
            : (alert('no sir'), false);
}
```

Furthermore `isNaN([value])` applies an implicit Number conversion for `[value]`, so you can use that too.

Keep in mind that `Number('')`, `Number(null)` or `Number('\t\n  ')` all evaluate to 0 and  `Number(true)` evaluates to 1. So, to be complete you'll have to do extra checks. Something like:

```
function isNumeric(prodFilterValue) {
    prodFilterValue = prodFilterValue && 
                      /stri/i.test(typeof prodFilterValue) && 
                      prodFilterValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/,'').length 
                       ? Number(prodFilterValue) 
                       : undefined;
    return prodFilterValue && prodFilterValue !== 0
            ? (alert('yeah!'), prodFilterValue) 
            : (alert('no sir'), false);
}
```

Comment: That will return true for `true` though, and false for `0`

Comment: this is good but when the value is 0.. it is false.. and when I changed to === 0 it is not functioning accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You can check if it is a number then would be float or integer.

```
function checkNumber(numb1)
{
  numb1 += "";   // to handle boolean when true / false is passed
  if(numb1.length == 0) return false; // to handle empty string like checkNumber("")

  if(isNaN(numb1))
      alert("It is a number");
  else
      alert("It is not a number");
}
```

Comment: Well, `isNaN("")` returns false, because of type coercion to 0, same with booleans.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for making me aware of it. I have changed the code a bit please have a look

Answer (score 0):

That's because `parseInt` and `parseFloat` will throw away any letters after a number, and parse `4K` as `4`. Add an additional condition: `isFinite(prodFilterValue)` and that should handle those cases.

`parseInt` and `parseFloat` will only return NaN if the first character cannot be converted to a number.

Be aware though, `parseInt` also handles values like hexadecimal:

```
parseInt("0xF"); // 15
```