# What does (obj.length === +obj.length) compare?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have been reading [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html) source code and noticed this compare in `_.each():`

```
(obj.length === +obj.length)
```

I know that + before a variable casts it to a number/integer. So in this cause

```
[1,2,3].length === +[1,2,3].length
```

is true. If I pass in an object:

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

`+obj.length` produces **NaN**

In the last case, I have

```
[1,2,3, {a: [4,5,6]}].length
```

which is 4. Casting it to a number.. Is still 4.

Deciding from the **else case**, I can see that this comparation is probably done to distinguish arrays from objects as in else case it uses:

```
  for (var key in obj) { ...
```

I fail to see any reason to use such a comparation. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: `NaN != NaN`  is true

Comment: Here are some interesting answers as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188998/obj-length-obj-length-in-javascript

Comment: I think it will fail if i have something like this: `var ob = { a: 5, length: 3 }`

Comment: @Francodi thanks! Didn't discover this :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, it's a way of testing the type of the `length` property is `Number` without using `typeof` **and** that the number is not `NaN`. So in effect:

```
if (typeof obj.length === "number" && !isNaN(obj.length))
```

The comparison `n === +n` will only be true for a number, because `===` tests both type and value, and `+n` will create a `Number` (possibly, as you found, the number `NaN`). And because `NaN === NaN` is false, it weeds those out too.

So it's a way of detecting, according to one definition ("has a numeric `length` that isn't `NaN`"), whether the object to be iterated is array-*like*. There are several array-like things in the JavaScript and browser world, such as the `arguments` pseudo-array and DOM's `NodeList`s.

---

Silly performance comparisons:

- `+` vs. `typeof` without worrying about `NaN`: [When `true`](http://jsperf.com/ways-to-check-number-type-when-true) | [When `false`](http://jsperf.com/ways-to-check-number-type-when-false)
- `+` vs. `typeof` and `isNaN`: [When `true`](http://jsperf.com/is-number-and-not-nan-when-true) | [When `false` (wrong type)](http://jsperf.com/is-number-and-not-nan-when-wrong-type) | [When `false` (`NaN`)](http://jsperf.com/is-number-and-not-nan-when-nan)

Upshot: Without the `NaN` aspect, `typeof` is faster (markedly so when the type is wrong). With the `NaN` aspect, `+` is faster when the result will be `true` and when it will be false because it's `NaN`, and slower (markedly so) when the result will be `false` because it's the wrong type. (Opera is, of course, different as always.)

Not that it's likely to matter in the real world (see "silly" above).

Comment: Thanks for the examples like arguments and NodeList!

Comment: more precisely, it tests if `length` is a number, but not NaN. They also could've used `isFinite` for this.

Comment: @thg435: **Very** good point. But `isFinite` is `false` for `Infinity`, too. :-)

Comment: @thg435: Of course, that (`isFinite` being `false` for `Infinity`) could be a good thing: With their current check, assuming they go with `for (i = 0; i < obj.length; ++i)`, they'll loop forever.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it's a fast way to distinguish an `Object` instance from an `Array` instance or '*Arrayish*' Objects (like `arguments`).

It would break if an `Object` instance contains a `length` property. Like `{a:1, length: 1}`, or as a result of `[].push.call({},'a value')` (result of that would be: `{0:'a value',length: 1}`). As demonstrated in [**this jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/am5Ld/)

Comment: or *array-like* objects.

Comment: @Felix: yep, added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

From the context, I think it's trying to figure out whether `obj` is an array, since iterating over one would require a sequential `for` loop rather than `for`-`in`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/367273

Answer (score 0):

The + operator returns the numeric representation of the object.As Your code +obj.length means its returning a number reference ....[this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators). You are getting +obj.length value as Number when its an array but it does not return length in case var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}; as its not an array...and when you are using [1,2,3, {a: [4,5,6]}].length its returning 4 as object is in array...